# Why isn't Visual Studio seeing MonoBehavior Class from Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Visual Studio is not seeing the MonoBehavior class.

I have tried un-installing and re-intalling several times and with both 2019 and 2020 versions.

When Visual Studio is opened, all of the correct using statements are at the top. MonoBehavior is not highlighted so auto-complete and class inspection/declarations don't work.

When I write code and then try to play it in Unity, it throws an error and won't play.

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome new user.  **Yes, this is currently a well-known problem with Unity**  Here is the only known solution:  https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-change-vscodes-targetframeworkversion.599476/#post-6242489

Comment: If anyone closes a question, please don't use a confusing "close reason".  This question is completely, perfectly "clear" and has total "details".

Comment: What you are describing seems to be no intelisense for unity in visual studio. I believe in `project settings` there is an area for `external tools`? You may have to select your code editor there. Best...

Comment: Is visual studio seing unity specific things like `vector3`? if not it's an intelasense issue